# Can't get the login for my site to work

Tags: php, mysqli

I updated my code and used mysqli this time   I don't get any more errors But it doesnt let me log in now.

```
<?php
$host = 'my host';
$user = 'me';
$PW = 'my password';
$dB = 'login';
$table = 'members';
$field = 'username';    
/* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $PW, $dB);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    exit();
}    
//Grab User submitted information
$name = $_POST['username']; //login name
$pass = $_POST['password'];  //login password    
/* Create a prepared statement */
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT f_name FROM $table WHERE $field=?
AND password=?")) {
    /* Bind parameters
    s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $name, $pass);
    /* Execute it */
    $stmt -> execute();        
    /* Bind results */

    $stmt -> bind_result($result);

    /* Fetch the value */

    $stmt -> fetch();

    if ($result == NULL) {
        echo "That combo of username and password is wrong!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Hello " . $result;
    }
    /* Close statement */
    $stmt -> close();
}
/* Close connection */
$mysqli -> close(); 
?>
```

I think it works now but even when I enter the correct ID & PW it says I didn't. I don't know why it would do this.

Comment: I can see a typo in your code: $_POST["usersname"] should be $_POST["username"] instead.

Comment: Plain text passwords? DON'T, really.

Comment: Hi. My name is Bobby Tables. You might want to search me on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query is invalid:

```
"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = $name"
// will result in 
"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = "
// if name is empty or
"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = SOMEVALUE"
// if name is "SOMEVALUE".
```

either way it's an invalid query string since SOMEVALUE is not interpreted as a string. You can try this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($name).'"');
```

mysql_real_escape_string() is used to escape characters that may cause problems/unwanted behaviour. **String in a query should be wrapped with quotes.**

I'd recommend looking into PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and reading about mysql injections.

Comment: Ok, I used mysqli and I get no errors but no matter my input it says "hello 'blank'"  So, I'm not sure if its working or not.  And when I use the proper username and password it doesn't echo f_name like requested.

Comment: So, now how do I ad a hash slinging slasher or what ever?  I heard it makes the input more secure.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is

```
 $_POST["usersname"]
```

is not defined.

when you use the `$name` in your query use this `mysql_real_escape_string($name)` .

if this is your code , its catastroph  for sql injections . you should change to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really should use mysqli. Standard `mysql_` functions are now deprecated, and for very solid reasons. Your code would look something like this, if it was rewritten using mysqli:

```
<?php
//Connect to database
$con = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'PW', 'dB');
if( $con->connect_errno > 0 ) {
    die( 'Unable to connect to dB!' );
}

//Grab User submitted information
$name = $_POST['username']; //login name
$pass = $_POST['password'];  //login password

// Make sure you do some validation of the $_POST data here

//Fetch user record from members table where username = inputed name
$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = ?");
// Binds $name as a string ('s') parameter to the first ? found in the statement
$statement->bind_param('s', $name);
$statement->execute();

//check to see if that username exists in DB & if not; stop, inform user & ask if he       wants to register
if ( $statement->num_rows === 0 ) {
    die('User does not exist. <a href="register.php">Click Here to Register</a>');
}

// Bind variables to the result; you need a variable for every column that is selected
$statement->bindResult($dbPassword);
$statement->fetch();

//check password, if pw entered != pw from pulled record then stop & inform user
if ($pass != $dbPassword) {
    die('Incorrect password, please try again.');
}

$statement->close();
$con->close();
```

If you are not using mysqli after all, know that the code that you wrote is not working because of 2 issues:

- You spelled `$name = $_POST["usersname"];` as `usersname` instead of `username`
- On the line `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = $name");` you need to escape the string like this: `username = " . mysql_real_escape_string( $name ) . "` otherwise quotes will not be added and the string will be misinterpreted as a token (also, there are SQL injection concerns)

Besides these points, it is important that you store passwords correctly in the database. You must not store passwords in plain text, as it is an enormous security risk. You need to store passwords as hashes, which are one-way functions that make it impossible (or at least harder) to obtain the password. I suggest you look into the [Crypt function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) in PHP. Used with the Blowfish algorithm and a suitable salt, it can provide excellent security, but further details about this are outside the scope of this post. You can find more information in the comments on that page.

EDIT: Updated the code to not use get_result()

Comment: Ok, I replaced my code in the process login page with the mysqli that you have above and now I get this error>"Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/content/81/11107981/html/test4/login.php on line 19" Line 19 is "$result = $statement->get_result();" Thanks btw to all you guys that responed. :)  Yes, I know its not secure and I have no validation yet, but just want to make it work first and will put that in later.

Comment: According to [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#105802) you are probably missing the right driver. To get around this, you need to replace some code. I'm editing my answer now to incorporate this change.